# Print the Letter X on a Background java Console application

Tags: java, console

Good Morning, I was hoping someone could help me?

Im doing a little java training, and i want to solve this algorithm, but im not quite sure how basic something like this could be, here is a image example of what the output should be in java, thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is an algorithm. You may hardcode it as well.

Comment: As @Peteef said. Call a System.out.printf() and use as parameter your string.

Comment: If you were to hardcode it, I would recommend you to first create the background (the numbers and the ='s). Its size is [78][24] so i assume you divide by 2 to find the middle, so the middle position would be at row 12 and column 39. To draw the X, you just replace the values by setting it to $, five times to each side. For example, the top left side of the X would be: [middleRow-n][middleColumn-n] (n being 1 to 5 ). Hope this makes sense.